# how to edit discount field access rights?

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo-10, odoo

I want to make sales manager only one who can give discounts in sales order line in odoo 10.

Edit: I need to make it displayed for all but only one who can modify

I have created the logic for discount and digits...

```
discount = fields.Float(string='Discount (%)',
digits=dp.get_precision('Discount'), groups="Sales Manager", default=0.0)
```

Any Suggestions will be helpful
Thanks!

Comment: you can use `attrs` to grant write access to a specific user or group.

Answer (score 1):

This will make the field invisible for all users sauf the manager user

```
<label for="discount" groups="sales_team.group_sale_manager"/>
<div name="discount" groups="sales_team.group_sale_manager">
     <field name="discount" class="oe_inline"/> % 
</div>
```

This will set readonly for all users sauf the manager users, with inherit

```
<record id="view_order_form_discount_readonly" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">sale.order.form.disount.readonly</field>
    <field name="model">sale.order</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/>
    <field name="groups_id" eval="[(6, 0, [ref('sales_team.group_sale_manager') ])]"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <field name='discount'/>
    </field>
</record>
```

Comment: it makes discount field disappered for other users. i need to make it displayed for all but only one who can modify

Comment: What do you mean by `sauf`.

Comment: `sauf` means `But` in frensh

Answer (score 0):

You have some options to do that. Two of them are:

1. add groups in views

```xml
<record id="view_order_form" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">view_order_form extension</field>
    <field name="model">sale.order</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form" />
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <!-- embedded form view -->
        <xpath expr="//field[@name='order_line']//form//label[@for='discount']" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="groups">sales_team.group_sale_manager</attribute>
        </xpath>
        <xpath expr="//field[@name='order_line']//form//div[@name='discount']" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="groups">sales_team.group_sale_manager</attribute>
        </xpath>
        <!-- embedded tree view -->
        <xpath expr="//field[@name='order_line']//tree//field[@name='discount']" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="groups">sales_team.group_sale_manager</attribute>
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

You need the proper xml resp. external IDs for the group, in this case `sales_team.group_sale_manager`. This is just one view override, keep in mind that there are two sale order form views in Odoo 10.

2. your way, changing the group directly on field

```py
discount = fields.Float(groups="sales_team.group_sale_manager")
```

It should be enough to just change the groups parameter, because the new API allows overriding fields without copying all parameters.

Comment: it makes discount field disappered for other users. i need to make it displayed for all but only one who can modify

Comment: Just edit you question and add this very important information.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the xml id of sale manager group.

> > groups -- comma-separated list of group xml ids (string); this restricts the field access to the users of the given groups only